The volume boot has only 0 bytes disk space remaining. Safe way to remove old kernels?
I have the same problem as this question, that is I get the warning:

The volume boot has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

on my Linux machine, version:
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal


Now the solution seems to be to remove old kernels, but I want to make sure I do this in a safe way.
What I have done so far:

Listed all of my kernels, with
dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-image-[[:digit:]].*" | tr "\t" ";" | cut -d ";" -f1
I have quite a few listed there.

Used uname -r to see which kernel I am currently using which is:
5.15.0-101-generic

Now looking to remove the old kernels this answer suggests running
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove


After using this command, one of the packages listed to be removed is
linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-92-generic
I know that you have to be careful with stuff related to the graphics card, as I have add to reboot my machine because of problems related to the graphics card.
Is linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-92-generic safe to remove?
Or is there a safer way to remove old kernels to clear space in the volume boot?

Depends on what you mean by "safe" and by "safer".

Is there a way of knowing whether removing that object will stop my machine from booting up. I was wondering, if people use a way that works for them and does not cause issues.

I am worried about the object that has to do with the graphics card, so because I am using another kernel are you sure that as the object name: linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.15.0-92-generic refers to another kernel it is safe to remove?

You could remove your old kernels, but more efficient would be to reduce your logs.
sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=2d

would purge your logs until the last two days - a will free up some diskspace.
To remove old kernels, I have stashed an old script:
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge


Thanks, I guess I would have to put sudo at the front

Great, I have completed this with sudo, and it has freed space. I will vote up,  but wait a bit to accept as answer to see if there are any answers about the way I was going to remove old kernels. Thanks again!

Sorry, I've added sudo and a working kernel removal command (with sudo ;-))

This is odd. Since when do systemd logs take up space on boot partition?

They don't. But you can't boot, if your "system" partition is full. That's the reason why I didn't document kernel thing at first, since they really reside in the boot partition. Except headers and possible dkms modules.
